# explanation of periodogram in layman's terms (or at least in a very simple way)

Tags: matlab, math, statistics

Could you please explain to me what a periodogram is and it's physical significance in a very basic and simple way?

I was looking at the figures in this document ([At page 5](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jnewton/stat626/topics/topics/topic4.pdf)). What is it's difference from the magnitude plot of a Fourier transform?

Is there any relationship between periodogram and spectrogram?

Can I have a very simple example using periodogram function of matlab as well?

Thank you

Comment: I found this link quite useful. Thought I'd share since I saw your posting as I was searching for an explanation. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-spectrogram-and-a-periodogram  -- I like the 2nd response (by Christiana Desouza) best.

Answer (score 4):

A periodogram is a method of calculating the power spectral density (PSD) of a signal. A simple periodogram involves dividing the data into windows and computing the PSD of each window, then taking the mean of these individual PSDs. Why? A raw PSD is a poor estimate in the statistical sense (chi-squared distribution? I suggest you check Bendat & Piersol). A simple periodogram fixes this issue but doesn't solve spectral leakage which can be fixed by certain types of windows (e.g. Hanning). I'm just scratching the surface...there are different algorithms to compute it - Welch and Blackman-Tukey for example.

In case you're wondering what a PSD is exactly:

Say you have a signal x(t) = (some noise component)*(sinusoid with frequency *f*). The power spectral density (usually Power/Hz vs frequency, on a log-log plot) of this signal will have a peak at the frequency *f*. It is useful for identifying frequency content in a signal.

Matlab has a built in periodogram function `periodogram` for your reference.

A spectrogram is a time-domain representation of the spectral density. At one time the signal might have stronger frequency content than at another time.